# Regex! Как ограничить ввод любого числа с максимальными 3 цифрами до и 6 цифрами после десятичной дроби c помощью regex replace?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Я написал примерное регуляторное выражение, но оно работает не верно.

```
 const getFormattedValueInput = (value: string) => {
    const removeСharsExceptNumberHyphenPoint = value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');
    const removeMultiplePoints = removeСharsExceptNumberHyphenPoint.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
    const removeMiddleHyphen = removeMultiplePoints.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
    const removeMultipleLeadingZeros = removeMiddleHyphen.replace(/^0+(\d)/gm, '$1');
    const formattedValue = removeMultipleLeadingZeros;
    const valueCoordinates = formattedValue.replace(/^-?\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,6})?$/g, '');
    return valueCoordinates;
  };
```

Мне нужно ограничить ввод в текстовое поле следующим образом:
первый знак может быть "-" , а может не быть,
далее три цифры до 180, после ввод запретить, если только это не десятичная дробь через "."
и после точки можно еще ввести шесть любых цифр.
В итоге максимально/минимальное число на ввод может быть таким:
-180.999999 /
180.999999

Comment: ^-?\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b\.?[0-9]{0,6}$

Comment: value.replace(/^-?\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b\.?[0-9]{0,6}$/g, ''); Таким образом я не могу ввести ни одно число.

Comment: @AndreyVolkov нужно через match https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a6g8rk

Answer (score 2):

```
-?(?<![\d.])(?:1[0-7]\d|180|\d{1,2})(?:\.\d{1,6})?(?![\d.])
```

`-?` - 0 или 1 символ *-*
`(?<![\d.])` - негативный просмотр назад, что нет незахваченных цифр
`(?:1[0-7]\d|180|\d{1,2})` - ограничение до 180, 00 так же будет валидно
`(?:\.\d{1,6})?` - необязательная группа для захвата цифр после точки
`(?![\d.])` - негативный просмотр вперед, отменяем выбор если впереди есть точка или цифра

Пример: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BILYGb/1)

Пример html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="inp">Input:</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp" pattern="-?(?<![\d.])(?:1[0-7]\d|180|\d{1,2})(?:\.\d{1,6})?(?![\d.])" title="диапазон от -180.999999 до 180.999999">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```